# drupal 8 configuring in GAE Issue

Tags: php, google-app-engine, drupal, drupal-7

I am using PHP GAE

1. Downloaded Drupal 8 stable from drupal.org
2. added App.yaml
3. Ran localhost port of 9083 which was configured but issue is drupal is bit slow and css is not loading

whether i need some thing to crack or add any configuration.

while i am searching in logs i found this as an example which is loading multiple times.

GET /core/install.php HTTP/1.1 200

if you found anything or share with me regarding for this issue are always welcome

Note : i am thinking due to the Css is not loading properly Gae takes much time.

Comment: Not only is it unclear what you're asking. Your question is not programming related and thus off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: how to configure drupal 8 in google app engine ?

Comment: That would be off-topic for stackoverflow.